# Visual Studio 2013 is running old code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have searched and found other topics on this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Visual Studio is running old code in debug mode and release mode. If I go to the actual directory and launch the exe, it is the latest code. It is a XAML project.

Things I have tried:
1) Deleted bin and obj folders
2) Rebuilt solution
3) Cleaned solution
4) Made sure the project is set to build in Configuration Manager

Update: I tried adding a new configuration in Configuration Manager. The path is totally different, and it still running the old code. The exe built with the new config is the right code when I launch it manually, but it seems like visual studio is running a cached version of the exe.

Comment: Use the debugger. The Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window tells you where it came from in the Path column. And change the Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run settings so you can never accidentally run on old build.   And always make an exclusion in your anti-malware product for the directory where you store projects.

Comment: The path is correct in the Module list while debugging. I also have checked the build and run settings. This project had been working previously. It just started doing this. My antivirus settings haven't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another gotcha I see a lot - be careful with shortcuts. If you are opening the solution via Recent Projects or another shortcut, try opening it via File -> Open or clicking on the solution file itself instead. I see a lot of developers looking at old code or the wrong branch because of this.

Can also try changing the assembly version number. Every once in awhile that will somehow make a difference.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see the second suggestion before. Changing the assembly version number did indeed fix it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! That one can be frustrating. Please mark as the correct answer when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly helped, but one thing is certain:

i marked .js file properties "Build  action" as "Compile".

Tryed to deploy (got an error of course), and changed it back to "Content".

Rebuild, deploy, run debugger and FINALY it works on my current code.

The Error is back on my "new old" code

**What i do is:**

click "Continue", go to opened IE window with my page\site, press CTRL + F5,

and what i see?

My new current code inside VS debugger...

Error is gone